# Angular 11 error TS7006: Parameter 'xyz' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

Using Angular 11 , trying to create a Template driven form.
The ts file has following code

```
submit(xyz){
var firstName = form.firstName;
console.log(firstName);

 }
```

SO I get the error

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'form' implicitly has an 'any' 
type.

  submit(xyz){
```

Comment: you most probably activated strict checks (and that's a good thing to do). what you didn't do is provide the type for xyz. it should be something like `submit(xyz: MyType)`. or to be more specific: every variable you define should have a type. the error says that form was defined without one, i suppose it's a class level field.

Comment: @MarkusDresch I have edited type to 'any' and it now says TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: Please share all the relevant code of the component. How do you initialize the `form`-object? What type is `xyz`? What type is `form`?

Comment: an object that's possibly null has to be null-checked in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Just give the function and the params a type like:

```
submit(xyz: object): void {
...
```

This is just typescript being extremely careful about your types. It's not an error. Just a warning.

Comment: it doesn't compile . I have added above and it gives TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. as error

Comment: Try adding the type `any` for now. It might compile.